# how to configure email template in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

how to configure wso2 email template

i have try the [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF200/Modifying+the+e-mail+Notification+Template) given by the wso2  it doesnot change

i got the email from wso2 while creating the new user in this format

```
    Dear rehan, 
Hi,
You have been registered to the LocationGuru EMM. Below is the link to enrol.


Thank you.

LocationGuru EMM Team. 

https://its.lg.com:9443/emm/api/device_enroll 
 Your password to your login : SqxCLF 

------------------------
```

i want the template with username as well as password

Answer (score 0):

This is found under configuration section of EMM. Login to EMM through admin credentials. Go to Configuraition and click on Settings tab. You will see the place to change the email template under General section.